# jQuery Adding DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This may be a simple answer, but I'm trying to add a dom-created element (i.e. `document.createElement(...)`) to a jQuery Selector.

jQuery has a great assortment of functions for adding html

- .html(htmlString)
- .append(htmlString)
- .prepend(htmlString)

But what i want to do is add a dom OBJECT

```
var myFancyDiv = document.createElement("div");
myFancyDiv.setAttribute("id", "FancyDiv");

// This is the theoretical function im looking for.
$("#SomeOtherDiv").htmlDom(myFancyDiv);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#SomeOtherDiv").append($(myFancyDiv));
```

Wrapping the DOM element in $(...), I'd expect you could add it with any of the jQuery DOM manipulation functions that take a jQuery element collection.

Comment: you don't need to wrap the DOM object with jQuery inside append. could just do `$("#SomeOtherDiv").append(myFancyDiv)`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it !

```
  $("#SomeOtherDiv").append('<div id="FancyDiv"></div>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make things simpler and faster by cutting out jQuery entirely for something this simple:

```
document.getElementById("SomeOtherDiv").appendChild(fancyDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in jQuery 1.4

```
$("<div/>",{
    id: 'FancyDiv'
}).appendTo("#SomeOtherDiv");
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
$("<div/>", {

  // PROPERTIES HERE

  text: "Click me",

  id: "example",

  "class": "myDiv",      // ('class' is still better in quotes)

  css: {           
     color: "red",
     fontSize: "3em",
     cursor: "pointer"
  },

  on: {
    mouseenter: function() {
      console.log("PLEASE... "+ $(this).text());
    },
    click: function() {
      console.log("Hy! My ID is: "+ this.id);
    }
  },

  append: "<i>!!</i>",

  appendTo: "body"      // Finally, append to any selector

});
```